# How to target js with kotlin kotest?

Tags: kotlin, kotest

I have been trying to setup kotest in a kotlin multiplatform project.
On the kotest starting guide it says to add this dependency to `commonTest`

```
implementation 'io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine:$version'
```

Unfortunately this does not resolve

```
Could not resolve io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine:4.4.1.
Required by:
    project :**strong text**
```

If add this dependency just to `jvmTest` it resolves. I can not find any guides to setup kotest for multiplatform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that kotest does not yet support the Kotlin compiler's IR backend for JS. This is [kotest issue 2037](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/2037). If you configure the LEGACY compiler backend for your JS multiplatform settings, it should work.

Kotest's [Quick Start](https://kotest.io/docs/quickstart) documentation does actually cover multiplatform configuration when you select the rightmost tab ("Multiplatform") in each section.

These are the relevant sections from a `build.gradle.kts` script which uses kotest with the IR backend on JVM along with the LEGACY backend on JS:

```kotlin
val kotestVersion = "4.4.1"

kotlin {
    jvm("backend") {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.useIR = true
        }
        withJava()
    }
    js("frontend", LEGACY) {
        browser {
            binaries.executable()
            testTask {
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    webpackConfig.cssSupport.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine:$kotestVersion")
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-property:$kotestVersion")
            }
        }
        val backendTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:$kotestVersion")
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks {
    // Tests
    withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```